# Bus seat reservation management

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

Currently I am getting this below **XML data format from URL**-

```
<Seat>
<ColumnNo>0</ColumnNo>
<Deck>2</Deck>
<Height>2</Height>
<IsAvailable>1</IsAvailable>
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>E</SeatLabel>
<Width>1</Width>
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>1</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<Height>2</Height> 
<IsAvailable>1</IsAvailable> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>SL5</SeatLabel> 
<Width>1</Width>
</Seat>

<Seat>
<ColumnNo>2</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<Height>1</Height> 
<IsAvailable>1</IsAvailable> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel/> 
<Width>1</Width>
</Seat>


<Seat>
<ColumnNo>3</ColumnNo> 
<Deck>1</Deck> 
<Height>2</Height> 
<IsAvailable>1</IsAvailable> 
<RowNo>0</RowNo>
<SeatLabel>SL1</SeatLabel> 
<Width>1</Width>
</Seat>
```

**And i have made image of layout the bus in which i want to make click on vacant seats and disable the seats in which available is 0**`( <IsAvailable>0</IsAvailable> )`

[image]

**I am confused as to how should I make the below layout and make then populate with the XML data which I am getting.**

- How to make the seating layout.
- How to Populate seat with XML data and which on click will be transferred to next activity for further process.
- enable disable the seat on basis of its availability.

**I am able to parse the data/values from XML in my code....I want that how to make the layout format and fit those XML values to particular seats.**

Comment: This is just a suggestion. Keep 2 images/drawables with 2 states seat enabled and disabled. parse the xml and get that IsAvailble value and add the image/drawable programatically to that layout.

Comment: @Raghavendra hmm....yaa but the layout is quite complex should use image buttion,listview,recycler or something else...could you refer any of the project online or github it will make more easy to understand.

Comment: Try this http://saurabhtomarsdk.blogspot.in/2014/06/android-bus-ticket-booking-code-with.html and https://www.dropbox.com/s/0oauvnihh7m5hj1/BusSeatBooking.rar?dl=0

Comment: @Raghavendra  yaa I did the same thing followed the same layout but its very unreal to change that into my layout like if I change the gaping/spaces with ...android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"  
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp" ....its changes in whole layout

Comment: this is actually double decker bus that i have shown with LOWER and UPPER seat layouts.

Comment: <http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm> tutorial to prase **XML** in **JAVA**. Then with the help of **if** statements you can handle what you want.

Comment: @Raghavendra  the matter of xml is not i have all the values in my variables that i have stored ...the thing is what should and how to make the layouts above and then i will pass the values to that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is `Too Broad`, but said that I'm happy to give some pointers: 1) User a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager, an ItemDecoration for the "Upper/Lower Deck" text on the sides and maybe use this lib (I wrote) https://github.com/eyeem/RecyclerViewTools to add "sections" to separate each row of seats. 2) Make your server return a JSON, XML parsing on mobile is a bad idea, always, it's forever a bad idea. 3) Enable/disable the seats on your adapter, depending on the data you parsed on 2)

Comment: @Budius thanks for the comment and please do not close this question...let intelligent people give their reviews and comments it will be surely healthy discussion .

Comment: @AndroidPutra how did you manage to create layout I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Table Layout for designing. You can use this code for designing Refer this [link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-deal-with-table-layout-in-android/28008)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Table 2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="B"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="D"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="E"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="F"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="G"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="H"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="I"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="J"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="K"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="L"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi ..thanks i made this last night you referred me for the table layout with the help of that i am able to made see this link http://i.stack.imgur.com/VjMkl.png ...i want the logic for setting the values which i am fetching from the online XML data to every seats.

Comment: if you find my answer useful for you then appreciate with  upvote

Comment: yaa sure your answer is useful my question included layout+adding data to the layouts from online xml concept

Comment: should i ask new question for that XML data to place to every imagebutton seats ?

Comment: ok i am going to ask another question for that and will link you also

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I did it , it's still in beta phase and I am trying to improve it . User can dynamically assign number of rows and seats in a rows(see text data )** .

Pre Beta code is available on [Github](https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Bus-Booking-Layout)

[image] [image]

[image]

Bus Layout activity with test Data

```
package com.serveroverload.busbooking;

import com.example.busbooking.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BusLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    // Test Data Inputs
    private final int NUMBER_OF_SEATS_LEFT_UPPER = 5;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_SEATS_RIGHT_UPPER = 5;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS_LEFT_UPPER = 1;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS_RIGHT_UPPER = 2;

    private final int NUMBER_OF_SEATS_LEFT_LOWER = 8;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_SEATS_RIGHT_LOWER = 7;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS_LEFT_LOWER = 1;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS_RIGHT_LOWER = 3;

    private Double totatCost = 0.0;
    private int totalSeats = 0;
    private TextView totalPrice;
    private TextView totalBookedSeats;

    private LayoutParams seatParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dynamic_bus_layout);

        // Fetch Required Layouts
        RelativeLayout busLayoutUpper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.upper_deck);
        RelativeLayout busLayoutBottom = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lower_deck);
        totalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_cost);
        totalBookedSeats = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_seats);

        // Layout Param for Seats
        seatParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        seatParams.weight = 1;
        seatParams.leftMargin = 5;
        seatParams.rightMargin = 5;

        // Add Bottom Seats
        addLeftSeats(NUMBER_OF_ROWS_LEFT_UPPER, NUMBER_OF_SEATS_LEFT_UPPER, busLayoutBottom);
        addRightSeats(NUMBER_OF_ROWS_RIGHT_UPPER, NUMBER_OF_SEATS_RIGHT_UPPER, busLayoutBottom);

        // Add Upper Seats
        addLeftSeats(NUMBER_OF_ROWS_LEFT_LOWER, NUMBER_OF_SEATS_LEFT_LOWER, busLayoutUpper);
        addRightSeats(NUMBER_OF_ROWS_RIGHT_LOWER, NUMBER_OF_SEATS_RIGHT_LOWER, busLayoutUpper);

    }

    /*
     * This function draw seats for right row
     */
    private void addRightSeats(int numberOfRowsRight, float numberOfSeatsInRow, ViewGroup busLayout) {
        int previousRow;

        // ADD RIGHT ROWS

        previousRow = 0;

        // Begin adding rows
        for (int rightRowCount = 0; rightRowCount < numberOfRowsRight; rightRowCount++) {

            // Adding Linear layout as row
            LinearLayout rightRow = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            rightRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            rightRow.setId(100 + rightRowCount);

            // make seats equal distance
            rightRow.setWeightSum(numberOfSeatsInRow);

            // if it is first row add row to window (ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)
            // else add row above window row (ABOVE)
            if (previousRow != rightRowCount) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, 100 + previousRow);
                newParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                rightRow.setLayoutParams(newParams);

            } else {

                // Layout params for first row (Window seat), adding margin and
                // bottom alignment
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightRowParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rightRowParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                rightRowParam.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                rightRow.setLayoutParams(rightRowParam);
            }

            // Add Seats in row we have added
            for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount <= numberOfSeatsInRow; rowCount++) {

                // Left Upper
                final Seat rightRowSeat = (Seat) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.seat, null);
                rightRowSeat.setLayoutParams(seatParams);
                rightRowSeat.setSeatNumber("SL" + rowCount);
                rightRowSeat.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                rightRowSeat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        updateCost(rightRowSeat);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seat # " + rightRowSeat.getSeatNumber(), 300).show();

                    }
                });

                // add seat to row
                rightRow.addView(rightRowSeat);

            }

            // and then add row to bus layout
            busLayout.addView(rightRow);

            // update row counter
            previousRow = rightRowCount;

        }
    }

    /*
     * This function draw seats for left row
     */
    private void addLeftSeats(int numberOfRowsLeft, float nuumberOfSeatsInRow, ViewGroup busLayout) {
        // Adding Left side rows

        int previousRow = 0;

        for (int leftRowCount = 0; leftRowCount < numberOfRowsLeft; leftRowCount++) {

            // Adding Linear layout as row
            LinearLayout LeftRow = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            LeftRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            LeftRow.setId(leftRowCount);

            // Equi distance seats
            LeftRow.setWeightSum(nuumberOfSeatsInRow);

            // if it is first row add row to window
            // else add row below window row (BELOW)
            if (previousRow != leftRowCount) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previousRow);
                newParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                LeftRow.setLayoutParams(newParams);

            } else {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams leftRowParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                leftRowParam.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                LeftRow.setLayoutParams(leftRowParam);
            }

            // Add Seats in row
            for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount <= nuumberOfSeatsInRow; rowCount++) {

                // Left Upper
                final Seat leftRowSeat = (Seat) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.seat, null);
                leftRowSeat.setLayoutParams(seatParams);
                leftRowSeat.setSeatNumber("SL " + rowCount);
                leftRowSeat.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                leftRowSeat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        updateCost(leftRowSeat);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seat # " + leftRowSeat.getSeatNumber(), 300).show();
                    }
                });

                LeftRow.addView(leftRowSeat);

            }

            // add row to bus layout
            busLayout.addView(LeftRow);

            // update row counter
            previousRow = leftRowCount;

        }
    }

    private void updateCost(final Seat ud_LeftWindowSeat) {

        if (ud_LeftWindowSeat.setSelected()) {

            totatCost += ud_LeftWindowSeat.getSeatPrice();
            ++totalSeats;

        } else {
            totatCost -= ud_LeftWindowSeat.getSeatPrice();
            --totalSeats;
        }

        totalPrice.setText("" + totatCost);
        totalBookedSeats.setText("" + totalSeats);
    }
}
```

Custom TextView for seats

```
package com.serveroverload.busbooking;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Seat extends TextView {

    public Seat(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public Seat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Seat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private String seatNumber;
    private Boolean isSelected = false;
    private Boolean isWomen = false;
    private Double seatPrice = 100.00;

    public Boolean getIsWomen() {
        return isWomen;
    }

    public void setIsWomen(Boolean isWomen) {
        this.isWomen = isWomen;
    }

    public Double getSeatPrice() {
        return seatPrice;
    }

    public void setSeatPrice(Double seatPrice) {
        this.seatPrice = seatPrice;
    }

    public Boolean getIsSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public Boolean setSelected() {

        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;

        if (getIsSelected()) {
            setBackgroundColor(0xff99cc00);

        } else {
            setBackgroundColor(0xff33b5e5);

        }

        return isSelected;

    }

    public String getSeatNumber() {
        return seatNumber;
    }

    public void setSeatNumber(String seatNumber) {
        this.seatNumber = seatNumber;

        setText(seatNumber);
    }

}
```

Activity layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        tools:context="com.serveroverload.busbooking.MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Lower Deck"
            android:textColor="#F00"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/upper_deck"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bus_outline"
            android:minHeight="150dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Upper Deck"
            android:textColor="#F00"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lower_deck"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bus_outline"
            android:minHeight="150dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_seats_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Number Of Seats"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_seats"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#0F0"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_cost_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Total Cost"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total_cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="#0F0"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Simple seat layout for layout inflating seat.xml

```
<com.serveroverload.busbooking.Seat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Bus outline shape drawable bus_outline.xml

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:radius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
```